# why isn't this button Constraints Design working?

Tags: ios, uistackview

Please I am a novice iOS developer. I am working an Application. I just created ios screen but this is not suite the design level, I need to configure it again. Here, Iam attaching the screenshots as well. Please find these screen and guide me
P.s. I am using stack view for the screen creation of the application

Here I am using one Vertical Stackview and 4 horizontal stack view

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share the code you attempted

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help need to include the code causing the issue, not just the desired and actual behaviour to be considered on-topic here on SO. Please include the code you use to set up the constraints or a screenshot of your Autolayout constraints on Storyboard.

Comment: Have you added spacing for your stackview? you can do that by clicking on your stack view, and click on attribute inspector and set a spacing. have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757832/4056108)

Comment: @Md Ibrahim Hassan plz check i am updating my code

Comment: Set amount of lines to 1

Comment: @ J Doe i am not getting your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will be helpful:

```
extension UIButton {
    func roundCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}

//Call this Extension like this:
 btn.roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20.0)
```

Comment: I have use code before                                                                  extension DesignableButton{
   func roundedButton(){
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .bottomRight],
                                     cornerRadii:CGSize(width:20.0, height:20.0))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer1
        
    }
}